# How to prevent browser's back button click?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I do not want to go my back history page through browser's back button. How I can do this?

Comment: cannot and should not be done.

Comment: You're almost certainly solving the *wrong* problem. If it's that inappropriate pages are ending up in the history, seek to solve *that* problem.

Comment: It can be done to an extent... you can remove the entries that you don't want the user to return to from the browser's history with JS (assuming you want to prevent the user from returning to a specific page). But it should definitely not be done. Don't do it!!

Comment: Please, don't touch the user expected behavior.

Comment: My User Experience Expert would kill me on the spot for even uttering such a sentence... Please listen to `ahren`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may disable it using HTML5 history API. There is [great article about this](http://jordanhollinger.com/2012/06/08/disable-the-back-button-using-html5) by Jordan Hollinger.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Damien's point here that you're solving the wrong problem. I wrote a blog post on this

> As a web developer, you have full control of your server code but only
>   limited control of the client in terms of scripting. You cannot even
>   gaurantee that the client will have any scripting capabilites (a user
>   may disable script until they trust your site), so
>   you should never design your site behaviour from the client's
>   perspective - i.e. trying to disable the back button of a browser.
>   Instead, if you need to implement behaviour so that when a logged out
>   user clicks the back button they are redirected to a login page, you
>   need to design your site so that this will occur. **Your server side
>   design should drive the client behaviour**

Full blog post is here - http://www.dylanmorley.com/blog/post/Web-Development-Disabling-the-back-button.aspx

While you can achieve the desired result using javascript, you cannot guarantee consistent behaviour across all devices in all modes (e.g - mobile browsing with script disabled)

Designing your server side code correctly will result in the correct client behaviour, without breaking the expected behaviour of the back button, with or without script enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but as @Ahren said you shouldn't.

You just need to develop SPA (Single page application).
It that case you will have only async requests to web server and your page will be updated partially.
As I understand by tags, you are using asp.net for developing.
So you can catch how to do it on asp.net official web site: [Samples: A Tour through SPA](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/spa-samples)

Comment: And what if a user opens a page in another window; then do smth in the original page, that will result to inconsistency of the original page kept in a separate window. And then user takes that separate page and tries to do smth again.....SPA does not aim to solve this problem I guess. This is not a problem at all. Simply the web-application should be able to be ready to get requests from "obsolete" pages. Am I not correct?

Comment: Well it doesn't solve inconsistency at all as it impossible in web environment and SPA just produces problems with history because in usual cases developers need to emulate history steps themselves. I've just shown a way how to build web app without any history. I'm am also dislike that kind of apps)

Comment: This had to be mentioned, IMO))

Answer (score 1):

you can expire your cache and you can achieve this functionality.

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean after log out from the site? if so i think this will help you : [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/149637/Disable-Browser-Back-Button-functionality-after-cl)

Comment: No. I do not want to go back through browsers's back button. Is it possible?

Comment: also if it can possible for a single button click, then you can provide these settings for all the button in your page and after page load event, so that it will become not possible at all. There are sites like that, which prevent you go to back, which is likely to not show your history. Somewhat tricky, but it will work for sure.