# How to prevent back after logout?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can i prevent back button after logout 
I tried to clear the cache from **global.asax.cs** but it doesn't work in (MVC 5 ) 
Please any other help?

Comment: Look like this is the [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem),  this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13490048/6577199) explains why it's bad idea to prevent user from going back by disable the back button

Answer (score 0):

Which type of Authentication are you using?

If you are using FormsAuthentication then use this code in your logOff Method

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
  AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
  Session.Abandon();
  Session.Clear();
  Response.Cookies.Clear();
  Session.RemoveAll();
  Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
  return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

Also use MVC's AuthorizeRoles attribute to make sure user redirects to login page once logged out

```
[AuthorizeRoles(UserRole.SocietyAdmin, UserRole.ClientAdmin)]
//Your ActionResult here
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}
```

Now whenever user is logged out of any authorized Page, he will go directly to login page when clicking back button.